# Future functions in DART working with ORACLE DART pub

Tags: oracle, dart

I'm using [oracledart pub](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/oracledart), and need to get the results returned as Map to the main function, I know it is a FUTURE function, and read about FUTURE, but looks still not clear for me, or I'm doing something wrong in my code, my function is as below:

```
void main() {
     var ORAresults = <Map>[];

     ORA()
          .then((results) => ORAresults = results) 
          .catchError((e) => 'Sorry, something wrong!'); 
}


ORA() {
    var results = <Map>[];
   connect(
               "SYSTEM","pswd",
               "(DESCRIPTION="
               "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))"
               "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))")
   .then(  
          (oracleConnection) {
          var resultset = oracleConnection.select("select * from vendors");

          while(resultset.next()) {
               results.add({"code":"vCode 1","name": "${resultset.getStringByName('NAME')}"});
            } 

      print('the results inside  $results');  // this works very well
      return results;
   }, 
   onError: (error) {
          print("Failed to connect: $error");
   });
}
```

When I run the above, I get this error:

```
  Breaking on exception: object of type NoSuchMethodError
```

the file dart:core-patch_object_patch.dart is opening, and pointing to:

```
  noSuchMethod(Invocation invocation) {
   =>   return _noSuchMethod(invocation.isMethod,        // this line is being highlighted!
        internal.Symbol.getName(invocation.memberName),
        invocation._type,
        invocation.positionalArguments,
        _symbolMapToStringMap(invocation.namedArguments));
    }
```

I thing the error is due to something wrong here, because if I removed these lines, the error disappear.:

```
         ORA()
          .then((results) => ORAresults = results) 
          .catchError((e) => 'Sorry, something wrong!');
```

any help pls.

Comment: What problem, specifically, are you having?

Comment: I got this error: Breaking on exception: object of type NoSuchMethodError

Comment: On which line do you get that?

Comment: Please post the full error message! ORA() does not return anything. So your code does not work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Tonio and @Robert, I think now I understood the meaning of the FUTURE better :)

I was able to solve the issue, based on your hints and explanations, as below:

in the server.dart

```
void handlePost(HttpRequest req) {
HttpResponse res = req.response;
     switch (req.uri.path) {
            ...
            case '/getVendors':
              getVendors(req);
              break;
            default:
              break;
           }     
   }

void getVendors(HttpRequest req) {
HttpResponse res = req.response;
addCorsHeaders(res);
print('${req.method}: ${req.uri.path}');

var vendors = <Map>[];
connect(
    "SYSTEM",
    "pswrd",
    "(DESCRIPTION="
      "(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))"
      "(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=XE)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))")
.then(  
  (oracleConnection) {
     var resultset = oracleConnection.select("select * from vendors");

     while(resultset.next()) {
        vendors.add({"code":"${resultset.getStringByName('CODE')}","name": "${resultset.getStringByName('NAME')}"});
      } 
      res.write(JSON.encode(vendors));
      res.close(); 
  }, 
  onError: (error) {
    print("Failed to connect: $error");
  });
}
```

and in the client.dart

```
 main(){
           HttpRequest request;  
           String serverResponse = '';  
    ...
 }
 void submit(){
     request = new HttpRequest();
     request.onReadyStateChange.listen(onData_getvendors); 

     var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8004/getVendors';  
     request.open('POST', url);
     request.send('');
  } 

  onData_getvendors(_){ 
      if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE && request.status == 200) {   // Data saved OK.                                
      for(Map vendor in JSON.decode(request.responseText)){
          vendor..children.add(new OptionElement(value: vendor['code'], data: vendor['name']));
       } 
      else if (request.readyState == HttpRequest.DONE &&
               request.status == 0) {         // Status is 0...most likely the server isn't running.
              serverResponse=request.responseText;
           }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your ORA() function does not return the `Future` it uses.  Change the `connect(` line to `return connect(`, and it should work.

When you do `ORA().then(...)`, you're using `ORA()`'s return value as a `Future`, but your `ORA()` function returns `null` (it has no `return` statement, so it returns `null` by default).  What you really want to do is return the `Future` you're building on with the `connect()`.

Comment: The error disappeared, but the ORAresults in this statement still  NULL..ORA()
   .then((results) => ORAresults = results)

Comment: Well, as @Robert pointed out in a comment, you're not doing anything with the results.  You're assigning it to a variable, but not doing anything with it.  The program exits as soon as it assigns `results` to `ORAresults`.  Try chaining another `.then()` after that one, and using (printing, maybe?) the `ORAresults`, or better yet, change the assignment to some actual use (printing, again?).

Comment: using this ORA()
   .then((results){ 
       print('results: $results');
        ORAresults=results;
        print('myORAresults: $ORAresults');
    }) .. it prints the correct ORAresults, but outside this loop, the ORAresults is NULL!

Comment: That's because you're dealing with `Future`s.  Outside the "loop" (it's not really a loop), the statements might be (and apparently are being) executed *before* the `Future`'s completion, so you're reading the `ORAresults` variable before it's being assigned.  You should put all the code that deals with the results in the `Future`'s completion handler.  If there is some other code that needs to be executed *after* the `Future` completes, it should be executed in the `then()` that your function returns (or in the `then()` that your `then()` returns).

Comment: `Future.then()` returns a `Future` itself: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/dartdoc-viewer/dart-async.Future#id_then  You can use this to "chain" your code:  `ORA().then(...).then(...).then(...)`.